# Use a low res image to find the high res version?

Tags: image-processing, search, file-search

I have a low resolution image. I know that I have a higher resolution version somewhere on a backup drive. Is there any software that can use the low res image to find the high res version?

Ideally, software would run on Mac… but I could make Windows work. Not sure on price… I guess it would depend on what's available.